# How to change opacity of element when scrolled to bottom within media query

Tags: javascript, css

I just want to ask. I want to make the product image thumbnail in shopify disappear when I scrolled down to bottom of the page, and I want a bit of transition with it.. I really can't figure out how to do this..

Here's my code..
https://jsfiddle.net/vsLdz4qb/1/

```
  function myFunction(screenWidth) {
    if (screenWidth.matches) { // If media query matches
      window.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
           document.getElementByClass("product-single__thumbnails").style.transition = "0.65s";
           document.getElementByClass("product-single__thumbnails").style.opacity = 0;
        }
      };
    }

  }

  let screenWidth = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 750px)");
  myFunction(screenWidth); // Call listener function at run time
  screenWidth.addListener(myFunction)
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct document method is `document.getElementsByClassName` and since it returns an array you need the first element of it so change this:

```
document.getElementByClass("product-single__thumbnails").style.transition = "0.65s";
document.getElementByClass("product-single__thumbnails").style.opacity = 0;
```

to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("product-single__thumbnails")[0].style.transition = "0.65s";
document.getElementsByClassName("product-single__thumbnails")[0].style.opacity = 0;
```

You can read more about the method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Yeah! and I added an else part and put back the opacity to 1 to show the product image thumbnail again whenever I scroll up and it worked like a charmmmmm!!! Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use **getElementsByClassName** in place of **getElementByClass**(This is not correct function)
and this will return an array like structure so you need to pass 0 index, if only one class available on page.

or you can try **querySelector(".product-single__thumbnails")**;

and for transition, you can define that in your **.product-single__thumbnails** class like: **transition: opacity .65s linear;** - use here which property, you want to animate.

```js
 <!-- [product-image] this is for product image scroll down disappear --> 

  function myFunction(screenWidth) {
    if (screenWidth.matches) { // If media query matches
      window.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
           document.getElementsByClassName("product-single__thumbnails")[0].style.opacity = 0;
        }
      };
    }

  }

  let screenWidth = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 350px)");
  myFunction(screenWidth); // Call listener function at run time
  screenWidth.addListener(myFunction)
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 1000px;
}
.product-single__thumbnails {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: opacity .65s linear;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-single__thumbnails">
  <p>red</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion too. I will try it! And yes, thank you for reminding me about the transition putting it into the css of class and not inside js. :)